# SQL CASE con múltiples AND

Tags: sql-server

Estoy intentando realizar una agrupación por clientes activos, clientes nuevos y clientes inactivos y que me muestre el total facturado (MEAS_TOTAL_TURNOVER_EUR). Debo ingresar el año actual y el anterior para determinar quién es nuevo o no.

Este es mi select

```
SELECT 

CASE   when (( MEAS_TOTAL_TURNOVER_EUR <> 0 and year = 2021 ) and ( MEAS_TOTAL_TURNOVER_EUR = 
              0  and year=   2021-1)) then 'Inactif' 
       when ( (MEAS_TOTAL_TURNOVER_EUR <> 0 and year = 2021 ) and ( MEAS_TOTAL_TURNOVER_EUR <> 
               0 and year = 2021-1)) then 'Actif customer'   
       when ( (MEAS_TOTAL_TURNOVER_EUR = 0 and year =2021 ) and  ( MEAS_TOTAL_TURNOVER_EUR <> 
              0  and year =  2021-1)) then 'New Customer' end ESTADO,

     COUNT (DISTINCT NOM_CLIENT) as NOMBRE_CLIENTS,
     SUM (MEAS_TOTAL_TURNOVER_EUR) AS TOTAL,
     Year,
     Year-1,
     MonthName

    FROM

     DWH.SOM.FACT_INVOICES

  INNER JOIN DWH.DIM.DIM_CALENDAR    ON DWH.SOM.FACT_INVOICES.DIM_CALENDAR_INVOICE_ID = 
  DWH.DIM.DIM_CALENDAR.DateKey
  INNER JOIN DWH.DIM.FAMILLE_STOCK   ON DWH.SOM.FACT_INVOICES.DIM_STOCK_FAMILY_ID  = 
  DWH.DIM.FAMILLE_STOCK.DIM_FAMILLE_STOCK_ID
  INNER JOIN DWH.DIM.CLIENT ON DWH.SOM.FACT_INVOICES.DIM_CLIENT_BILLTO_ID = 
  DWH.DIM.CLIENT.DIM_CLIENT_ID
  INNER JOIN DWH.DIM.DIM_REPRESENTANT ON DWH.SOM.FACT_INVOICES.DIM_REPRESENTANT_ID = 
  DWH.DIM.DIM_REPRESENTANT.DIM_REPRESENTANT_ID

 WHERE ((FACT_INVOICE_ID LIKE 'HEXIS PTY%' AND FAMILLE_STOCK.GROUPE_FAMILLE_STOCK = 'Core Business' AND YEAR = 2021) OR  (FACT_INVOICE_ID LIKE 'HEXIS PTY%' AND FAMILLE_STOCK.GROUPE_FAMILLE_STOCK = 'Core Business' AND YEAR = 2021 -1 ))

 GROUP BY CASE  
   when( ( MEAS_TOTAL_TURNOVER_EUR <> 0 and year = 2021 ) and ( MEAS_TOTAL_TURNOVER_EUR = 0  
         and year= 2021-1)) then 'Inactif' 
   when (( MEAS_TOTAL_TURNOVER_EUR <> 0 and year = 2021)  and ( MEAS_TOTAL_TURNOVER_EUR <> 0  
          and year = 2021-1)) then 'Actif customer'   
   when (( MEAS_TOTAL_TURNOVER_EUR = 0 and year =2021 ) and  ( MEAS_TOTAL_TURNOVER_EUR <> 0  
          and year = 2021-1)) then 'New Customer' end, Year, MonthName, Year -1

          order by Year, MonthName, year-1
```

Sé que tengo el problema en el case por el AND, pues me arroja NULL en el ESTADO. Cada caso debe cumplir múltiples condiciones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es una idea de cómo recibo

```
                     2020                      2021
cliente  comercial  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 12   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
1001     Ana          8 5 4 2                 2 3 5 7
1002     Ana        5 9 4 3 1                
1003     Ana                                          6 5 9
1004     Romain       6         4 9             2   3  9
1005     Romain            5 9 6                    
1006     Romain                                  5 9     6
```

Esta es la explicación de la tabla de precedente

```
                                    2020    2021
                 clientes activos:   1        0   
                 nuevos              0        1
                 activos             1        1
```

Comment: Las condiciones en todos los casos se excluyen entre sí, por ejemplo "que el monto sea distinto de 0 y el año sea 2021 y que el monto sea 0 y el año sea 2020", me parece que el and del medio es lo que está mal ¿no debería ser un or?

Comment: es que se deben cumplir las dos condiciones, ese es mi problema, es decir para ACTIVO, debe contener tanto informacion en el año  actual como en el año  precendent

Comment: Es que justamente no se pueden cumplir esas dos condiciones, como se puede cumplir una condición que dice que el año tiene que ser el 2021 y 2020 al mismo tiempo?

Comment: Entiendo lo que quieres hacer, pero necesito que compartas un poco de datos de prueba para comprobar que la solución funcione.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu interes,  trate de ingresar un poco de informacion

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta no está muy bien planteada, porque es un escenario que no se puede reproducir, por tanto es todo basado en opiniones.

Pero vamos a intentar ayudarte antes de que se cierre.

Cuando existe un escenario como este, lo primero es validar que lo que crees que es = ES.

Como no hay nada mejor que verlo, así es como localizó los agujeros cuando se plantea una expresión compleja.

```
With data as (
SELECT MEAS_TOTAL_TURNOVER_EUR 
FROM
        DWH.SOM.FACT_INVOICES
    INNER JOIN DWH.DIM.DIM_CALENDAR 
        ON DWH.SOM.FACT_INVOICES.DIM_CALENDAR_INVOICE_ID = DWH.DIM.DIM_CALENDAR.DateKey
    INNER JOIN DWH.DIM.FAMILLE_STOCK   
        ON DWH.SOM.FACT_INVOICES.DIM_STOCK_FAMILY_ID  = DWH.DIM.FAMILLE_STOCK.DIM_FAMILLE_STOCK_ID
    INNER JOIN DWH.DIM.CLIENT 
        ON DWH.SOM.FACT_INVOICES.DIM_CLIENT_BILLTO_ID = DWH.DIM.CLIENT.DIM_CLIENT_ID
    INNER JOIN DWH.DIM.DIM_REPRESENTANT 
        ON DWH.SOM.FACT_INVOICES.DIM_REPRESENTANT_ID = DWH.DIM.DIM_REPRESENTANT.DIM_REPRESENTANT_ID
 WHERE (
            (
            FACT_INVOICE_ID LIKE 'HEXIS PTY%' 
            AND FAMILLE_STOCK.GROUPE_FAMILLE_STOCK = 'Core Business' 
            AND YEAR = 2021) 
        OR  
            (FACT_INVOICE_ID LIKE 'HEXIS PTY%' 
            AND FAMILLE_STOCK.GROUPE_FAMILLE_STOCK = 'Core Business' 
            AND YEAR = 2021 -1)
       )
)
select
    * 
from data;
```

Como puedes observar, no es más que la query, identificando un poco las estructura y el where por si hubiera algo mal formado. Esto no tiene nada especial, salvo el hecho que me llama la atención que usas `year` y no como función. Raro, porque es una palabra que identifica a una función, y no se debería de usar, al menos así. Pero válido.

Si estás evaluando una expresión, puedes ir comprobándola. Y este es el punto clave. Si observas, te he dado la consulta en una cte.

```
With data as (
SELECT MEAS_TOTAL_TURNOVER_EUR, year, 
    case when MEAS_TOTAL_TURNOVER_EUR<>0 then 1 end as comprobandoMeasTotalTurnoverEur,
    case when year=2021 then 1 end ComprobandoYear2021,
    case when MEAS_TOTAL_TURNOVER_EUR<>0 And year=2021 then 1 end comprobandoMesAndYear2021,
    case when (MEAS_TOTAL_TURNOVER_EUR<>0 And year=2021) 
        And     
              (MEAS_TOTAL_TURNOVER_EUR = 0 And year=2021-1) 
              then 1 end comprobandoMesAndYear2021AndMesAndYear2021Menos1

FROM
        DWH.SOM.FACT_INVOICES
    INNER JOIN DWH.DIM.DIM_CALENDAR 
        ON DWH.SOM.FACT_INVOICES.DIM_CALENDAR_INVOICE_ID = DWH.DIM.DIM_CALENDAR.DateKey
    INNER JOIN DWH.DIM.FAMILLE_STOCK   
        ON DWH.SOM.FACT_INVOICES.DIM_STOCK_FAMILY_ID  = DWH.DIM.FAMILLE_STOCK.DIM_FAMILLE_STOCK_ID
    INNER JOIN DWH.DIM.CLIENT 
        ON DWH.SOM.FACT_INVOICES.DIM_CLIENT_BILLTO_ID = DWH.DIM.CLIENT.DIM_CLIENT_ID
    INNER JOIN DWH.DIM.DIM_REPRESENTANT 
        ON DWH.SOM.FACT_INVOICES.DIM_REPRESENTANT_ID = DWH.DIM.DIM_REPRESENTANT.DIM_REPRESENTANT_ID
 WHERE (
            (
            FACT_INVOICE_ID LIKE 'HEXIS PTY%' 
            AND FAMILLE_STOCK.GROUPE_FAMILLE_STOCK = 'Core Business' 
            AND YEAR = 2021) 
        OR  
            (FACT_INVOICE_ID LIKE 'HEXIS PTY%' 
            AND FAMILLE_STOCK.GROUPE_FAMILLE_STOCK = 'Core Business' 
            AND YEAR = 2021 -1)
       )
)
select
    * 
from data
```

Por tanto podemos hacer un where en la salida de la cte por el nombre que le hemos puesto a cada una de las columnas case un where, para buscar si es null o 1.

Ahora bien, no obstante parece un error de concepto, el hecho de que la columna MEAS_TOTAL_TURNOVER_EUR, la uses como una función de suma y en otra columna sin sumar intentes dar un estado.

Diría que lo más lógico es, calcular primero la suma por año, y de el extraer el estado. Porque si en una fila tiene un cero y en la siguiente tiene un varlor superior para el mismo año, cual es su valor.....Ya no digamos si la columna tiene null por .....

```
declare @valor int
select 
    case when @valor <> 0 then 'true' else 'false' end,
    case when @valor = 0 then 'true' else 'false' end,
    case when @valor is null then 'true' else 'false' end
```

[image: Res]

Si, aunque parezca extraño, algo que es null evaluando la expresión me ha devuelto que es falso en distinto de cero y también que es falso en igual a 0.

Comment: Gracias por tu informacion, trate de recrear un ejemplo sencillo de los datos que tengo, sobre todo a lo que se refiere al saber que cliente es activo, inactivo y nuevo. mil gracias por tu interes

Comment: Por ejemplo para el caso de cliente activo, con solo un valor que se encuentre en alguno de los meses tanto en el año 2021 y en el año 2020, valida, es decir puede que alguno de los meses este en 0

Comment: Si unas filas tienen 0 y otras uno, y estás retornando agrupado, es posible que no funcione bien, Porque unas veces puede tener 0 y otras uno. No es lógico evaluar fila por fila, algo que en el mismo conjunto estas recogiendo agrupado. Hazlo en una `cte` o Tabla Temporal, agrupado por años, y valida en la salida el resultado de cada conjunto. `with cte as (Select sum(MEAS_TOTAL_TURNOVER_EUR) as total, year....group by year) Select case when total = 0 and year = 2021 then 1 .....`